# document.on click executing multiple times

Tags: jquery

I am showing a view as modal popup and that view has a table as given below

```html
<table id="tdServiceList" class="table table-bordred table-striped">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>SL. No.</th>
            <th>Status</th>

            <th>Service Name</th>
            <th>Public Service No</th>
            <th>Dept</th>

        </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td><a class="click">[+]</a></td>
            <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;1</td>
            <td>KHARWAR NAGAR-SOMESHWAR JN-NEW</td>
            <td>105</td>
            <td>BRT</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="5">
                <table id="tdServiceListDetails" class="table table-bordred table-striped" style="display: table;">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Master Schedule Name</th>
                            <th>Action</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Demo master schedule</td>
                            <td>
                                <button alt="View Master Schedule Plan" title="View  Master Schedule Plan" onclick="ViewMasterSchedule( 1036,4 )" class="btn btn-default btn-xs"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open"></span></button>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>master sch2</td>
                            <td>
                                <button alt="View Master Schedule Plan" title="View  Master Schedule Plan" onclick="ViewMasterSchedule( 1037,4 )" class="btn btn-default btn-xs"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open"></span></button>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>master schedule june</td>
                            <td>
                                <button alt="View Master Schedule Plan" title="View  Master Schedule Plan" onclick="ViewMasterSchedule( 1052,4 )" class="btn btn-default btn-xs"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open"></span></button>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><a class="click">[+]</a></td>
            <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;2</td>
            <td>UDHANA-SACHIN G.I.D.C NAKA</td>
            <td>101A</td>
            <td>BRT</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="5">
                <table id="tdServiceListDetails" class="table table-bordred table-striped" style="display: none;">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Master Schedule Name</th>
                            <th>Action</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td>1010 schedule1</td>
                            <td>
                                <button alt="View Master Schedule Plan" title="View  Master Schedule Plan" onclick="ViewMasterSchedule( 1039,1010 )" class="btn btn-default btn-xs"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open"></span></button>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>1010 sch2</td>
                            <td>
                                <button alt="View Master Schedule Plan" title="View  Master Schedule Plan" onclick="ViewMasterSchedule( 1040,1010 )" class="btn btn-default btn-xs"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open"></span></button>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>primary master schedule</td>
                            <td>
                                <button alt="View Master Schedule Plan" title="View  Master Schedule Plan" onclick="ViewMasterSchedule( 1041,1010 )" class="btn btn-default btn-xs"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open"></span></button>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>primary2</td>
                            <td>
                                <button alt="View Master Schedule Plan" title="View  Master Schedule Plan" onclick="ViewMasterSchedule( 1042,1010 )" class="btn btn-default btn-xs"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open"></span></button>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>primary3</td>
                            <td>
                                <button alt="View Master Schedule Plan" title="View  Master Schedule Plan" onclick="ViewMasterSchedule( 1043,1010 )" class="btn btn-default btn-xs"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open"></span></button>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>demo plan  new</td>
                            <td>
                                <button alt="View Master Schedule Plan" title="View  Master Schedule Plan" onclick="ViewMasterSchedule( 1044,1010 )" class="btn btn-default btn-xs"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open"></span></button>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>surat plan</td>
                            <td>
                                <button alt="View Master Schedule Plan" title="View  Master Schedule Plan" onclick="ViewMasterSchedule( 1045,1010 )" class="btn btn-default btn-xs"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open"></span></button>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>surat plan new</td>
                            <td>
                                <button alt="View Master Schedule Plan" title="View  Master Schedule Plan" onclick="ViewMasterSchedule( 1046,1010 )" class="btn btn-default btn-xs"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open"></span></button>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>surat mc</td>
                            <td>
                                <button alt="View Master Schedule Plan" title="View  Master Schedule Plan" onclick="ViewMasterSchedule( 1047,1010 )" class="btn btn-default btn-xs"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open"></span></button>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>demo surat mc</td>
                            <td>
                                <button alt="View Master Schedule Plan" title="View  Master Schedule Plan" onclick="ViewMasterSchedule( 1048,1010 )" class="btn btn-default btn-xs"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open"></span></button>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>demo 41</td>
                            <td>
                                <button alt="View Master Schedule Plan" title="View  Master Schedule Plan" onclick="ViewMasterSchedule( 1051,1010 )" class="btn btn-default btn-xs"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open"></span></button>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Here the outer table body and inner tables are created using jquery.

```js
  function DisplayServiceDetails(spaging, offset) {
        debugger;
        currentPageNo = spaging;
        var url = "/ServiceManagement/TransitPlanServiceDisplay/";
        var data = { 'paging': spaging, 'Offset': offset };
        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            data: data,
            cache: false,
            type: "POST",
            success: function (outPut) {
                var data = JSON.parse(outPut);
                if (data.length > 0) {
                    $('#tdServiceList tbody').remove();

                    for (var x = 0; x < data.length; x++) {
                        var serialno = x + 1;
                        var result = data[x];
                        var blockingStatus = '';
                        var addRoute = '@Url.Content("~/Areas/ScheduleManagement/ServiceManagement/ViewService")';
                        var id = '?id=' + result.ServiceGroupId

                        /********* updating blocking status*********/
                        if (result.TripStatus == 0) {
                            blockingStatus = ' <input type="text" class="service-status  timesheet-requested " disabled >';
                        }
                        else if (result.BlocKingStatus == 0 && result.TripStatus == 1) {
                            blockingStatus = ' <input type="text" class="service-status  timesheet-created " disabled >';
                        }
                        else if (result.BlocKingStatus == 1) {
                            blockingStatus = '<input type="text" class="service-status  pending" disabled  >';
                        }
                        else if (result.BlocKingStatus == 2) {
                            blockingStatus = '<input type="text" class="service-status  blocking-done" disabled >';
                        }
                        else if (result.BlocKingStatus == 3) {
                            blockingStatus = '<input type="text" class="service-status  approved" disabled >';
                        }
                        /******** hard coding service priority**********/
                        var priority = '';
                        if (result.ServicePriority == 1) {
                            priority = "High";
                        }
                        else if (result.ServicePriority == 2) {
                            priority = "Normal";
                        }
                        else if (result.ServicePriority == 3) {
                            priority = "Low";
                        }
                        /******** Enable blocking only after doing Trip generation**********/
                        var checkbox = '';
                        if (result.TripStatus == 0) {
                            checkbox = "<input type='checkbox' id=" + result.ServiceGroupId + " disabled  class='checkthis'/>";
                        }
                        else if (result.TripStatus == 1) {
                            checkbox = "<input type='checkbox' id=" + result.ServiceGroupId + "  class='checkthis' />";
                        }
                        /*********Enable/Disable view Blocking sheet*********/
                        var viewBlocking = '';
                        if (result.BlocKingStatus == 2 || result.BlocKingStatus == 3) {
                            viewBlocking = " <a alt='View Blocking Sheet' title='View Blocking Sheet' href=" + "@Url.Content("/ScheduleManagement/Blocking/BlockingSheet")" + id + " class='btn btn-default btn-xs'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-list-alt'></span></a>";
                        }
                        else {
                            viewBlocking = " <a alt='View Blocking Sheet' title='View Blocking Sheet' class='btn btn-default btn-xs linkdisabled'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-list-alt'></span></a>";
                        }
                        /******************/

                        var innerTableContent = '';

                        for (var m = 0; m < result.MasterSchedules.length; m++) {
                            innerTableContent += '<tr><td>' + result.MasterSchedules[m].MasterScheduleName + '</td>' +
                                "<td><button alt='View Master Schedule Plan' title='View  Master Schedule Plan' onclick='ViewMasterSchedule( " + result.MasterSchedules[m].ServiceMasterScheduleID + "," + result.ServiceGroupId + " )' class='btn btn-default btn-xs'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open'></span></a> </td></tr>";
                        }

                        $("#tdServiceList").append("<tr><td><a class='click' >[+]</a></td>" +
                            "<td>" + checkbox + '&nbsp;&nbsp;' + serialno + "</td>" +
                                                      "<td>" + result.ServiceGroupeName + "</td>" +
                             "<td>" + result.PublicServiceNo + "</td>" +
                                                        "<td>" + result.Department + "</td>" +

                                                     @*  "<td> <a alt='View' title='View' href=" + "@Url.Content("/ScheduleManagement/ServiceManagement/ViewService")" + id + " class='btn btn-default btn-xs'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open'></span></a> " +
                            "<a alt='Edit' title='Edit' href=" + "@Url.Content("/ScheduleManagement/ServiceManagement/CreateService")" + id + " class='btn btn-default btn-xs'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-pencil'></span></a> " +
                            //"<a alt='Delete' title='Delete' href=" + "@Url.Content("/ScheduleManagement/ServiceManagement/DeleteService")" + id + " class='btn btn-default btn-xs'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-trash'></span></a>" +
                            "<button class='btn btn-default btn-xs' data-title='Delete' onclick='GetId( " + result.ServiceGroupId + " )'  data-toggle='modal' data-target='#delete'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-trash'></span></button></span>" +
                            viewBlocking + "</td>" +*@
                            "</tr>" +
                            "<tr>            <td colspan='5'>" +

                    "<table id='tdServiceListDetails' class='table table-bordred table-striped' style='display: none;'>" +
                            "<thead><tr><th>Master Schedule Name</th><th>Action</th></tr></thead><tbody>" +
                            innerTableContent + "</tbody></tr></table></td></tr>"
                            );

                        serialno = "";
                    }

                    //------------------pagination-----------

                    debugger;
                    var spagee = 1;
                    var stotalItems = 0;
                    if (spaging == 0) {
                        if (data.length > 0) {

                            stotalItems = data[0].TotalCount;
                            spagee = (stotalItems / offset);
                        }
                        //pagenum ends
                    } //endif
                    else {
                        spagee = spaging
                        if (data.length > 0) {
                            stotalItems = data[0].TotalCount;
                        }
                    }
                    //else end
                    var offset = 20;
                    var spageCount = ((spagee - 1) * offset) | 0;
                    var stotalPages = 0;

                    var Previous = 0;
                    var Next = 0;

                    stotalPages = (stotalItems / offset) | 0;
                    if (stotalItems % offset != 0) {
                        stotalPages++;
                    }

                    PagesCount = stotalPages;
                    Previous = spagee - 1;
                    if (stotalItems > offset) {
                        Next = spagee + 1;
                    }
                    else {
                        Next = 0;
                    }
                    var spaging = '';
                    spaging += "<ul>";
                    if (Previous != 0) {
                        spaging += "<li>";
                        spaging += "<a href=\"javascript:DisplayServiceDetails(" + Previous + ");\"  > Previous </a>";
                        spaging += "</li>";
                    }
                    //end previous
                    for (var p = 1; p <= PagesCount; p++) {
                        spaging += "<li>";
                        if (p == Previous + 1) {
                            spaging += "<a href=\"javascript:DisplayServiceDetails(" + p + ");\"  class = \"active\" >" + p + "</a>";
                        }
                            //end if
                        else if (p <= 10) {
                            spaging += "<a href=\"javascript:DisplayServiceDetails(" + p + ");\"  >" + p + "</a>";
                        }
                        //endelse
                        spaging += "</li>";
                    }
                    //end for
                    if (Next != PagesCount + 1 && Next != 0) {
                        spaging += "<li>";

                        spaging += "<a href=\"javascript:DisplayServiceDetails(" + Next + ");\"  > Next </a>";
                        spaging += "</li>";
                    }
                    //end next
                    spaging += "</ul>";
                    //   alert(spaging);
                    $('#pagination').html(spaging);
                    //---------------------------------------

                }
                else {
                    $('#tdServiceList tbody').remove();
                    $("#tdServiceList").append("<tr><td> No Records found</td></tr>");

                }
            },
            error: function (response) {
                alert("error : " + response);
            }
        });
    }
```

And i have used toggle option to show the inner table

```js
 // this is added for testing purpose. tried to off click event
 $(document).off('click').on('click', '[class=click]', function () {
        // function body
        alert('2');
    });
    $(document).on('click', '[class=click]', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        debugger;
        alert('1');

        $(this).closest('tr').next().find('table:first').toggle();
    });
```

Now the issue here is, data toggle options are executing multiple times. so first time it will work properly. second time it won't work and third time again its working fine.

I tried adding   $(this).off('click');  and return $document.off('click', e); also in on click function.. but both didn't work.

Comment: Try adding `e.stopImmediatePropagation();`

Comment: where to add this? Inside the click event handling?

Comment: $(document).off('click', '[class=click]').on('click', '[class=click]', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        debugger;
        alert('1');

        $(this).closest('tr').next().find('table:first').toggle();
        e.stopImmediatePropagation();

    });
i tried like this.. but couldn't see any change

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to `unbind` the event listener and `re-bind` it like:

```
$(document).off('click', '[class=click]').on('click', '[class=click]', function () {
```

it will help.

**Note:** Do not include the JS inside the popup view, otherwise it will load again and again, instead put it in the parent view and use the above code.

Comment: Hi, 
I tried it.... but its same.. no change.
 $(document).off('click', '[class=click]').on('click', '[class=click]', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        debugger;
        alert('1');

        $(this).closest('tr').next().find('table:first').toggle();

    });

Comment: When i open the popup for the first time the click event is executing only once. when i close the popup window and reopen it  then the event will fire 2 times and if i close and try again the event will fire 3 times .. like that it is executing

Comment: The same issue I had, but the above code resolved mine.

Comment: Is the js file is also on the same popup page? Or it is in the parent window ?

Comment: tables are in popup view and js is also in same view

Comment: Thanks a lot Mayank